# What's the easiest way to store objects/a map filled with objects in a file?

Tags: java, object, save

I'm relatively new to Java and never saved something to a file. I'd like to know what's the easiest way for beginners to store and read user defined objects in/from a file. I've already managed to put them into a map, now I have to save this map in some kind of file. I know there are different ways to do so, but which data type and method do you recommend for example? 
And how would I get a single object out of the file instead of "everything"?

Here you can see my object and the map where I put the created objects into.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Question number1 = new Question("What is the right answer?",
        new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, 3, 1.0);
}

public class Question {

public String question;
public String[] answers;
public int solution;
public double priority;
static int counter;
public static Map<Integer, Question> Database = new TreeMap<Integer,Question>();

public Question(String que, String[] ans, int sol, double prio){
this.question = que;
this.answers = ans;
this.solution = sol;
this.priority = prio;
Database.put(++counter, this);

}
```

Comment: A simple suggestions might be a csv file, where you put one object per line and separate their attribute values with a comma (or semicolon, may be better in certain locales).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) to save your objects to files. Java has built in serialization though you can also use a library such as [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) to save your map to JSON.